# FTP upload of the web-accessible file placed on a 3rd party server without prior downloading

Tags: php, ftp

How to, using PHP script placed on server(A) upload file located on server(B)* throught FTP to server(C) without downloading the file?

*the only known/accessible URL of the file points to server(Z), which 301-redirects to the original file on server(B)

Answer (score 1):

Should be moderately simple:

- Use cURL with redirect following to download the file from Z-B to A
- Create check sum of file on A
- Use FTP to upload the file from A to C
- Download file on C to file A and create checksum
- Validate upload with checksum comparison
- Remove file from A if no longer needed

Comment: question edited - uploading the file thru FTP without prior downloading (FXP?)